# Efficient way to get nearest point

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, nearest-neighbor

I have two lists of points stored as rows of 2d arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

For each point in `b`, I would like to get the indices of the nearest point in `a`. Currently, my solution is

```
f = lambda x: np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(a - x, axis=1))
print(list(map(f, b)))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have tried `np.vectorize(f)(b)`, but it does not work.

Comment: In the linked Q&A's solution, simply skip the final indexing to `matrix` part.